# Strip control inside Editor right side end in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am doing an app in which i have to submit data having 8 entries one by one in a stack. I used the scrollview.But when there is no stripe outside on my stripe in editor, please anyone found that solution

Comment: Do you have a picture of what exactly you are trying to accomplish? Do you mean you don't want the stripes listview have? Then set SeperatorVisibility="none" (syntax is something like that)

Comment: Can you please share us some codes or screenshot about this problem?